# DBT view entire generated sql along with sql headers, macros and hooks - dry run

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbt

- I would like to view the entire sql that dbt is going to execute with `dbt run` / `dbt build`.
- dbt compile just generates the SELECT SQL's that are present in dbt models. They do not generate the SQL headers like `INSERT INTO` / `MERGE INTO` / `COPY INTO` / `CTAS`.
- The above can be seen under target/run only after a dbt build is run.
- Now, I would like to view these compile sql before running the model so as to not audit the sqls better.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the only way to access `target/run/`, where all the SQL `create` statements can be found, is by first running a `dbt run/build` command. There's not such `dry run` option as to my knowledge

Comment: @AleixCC Is there any macros that I can use with run-operation with an argument as model reference, which will generate the entire SQL?

Comment: I guess you could create a custom macro, yes. Not sure if the complexity this involves would be worth it, though